# Time-derivative of the euclidean norm squared doesn't explicitly depend on time?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

If V=$\mathrm \Vert x \Vert_\mathrm{}^2$, then $\dot V=2V(V-1)$ according to a controls textbook making an off-hand mathematical observation.

I can possibly understand the 2V, but am not sure where the (V-1) comes from. Could anyone show this derivation or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems odd. If $x$ has a meaning of length, then $V$ has a meaning of length squared. Its derivative with respect to time is "length times velocity", yet the product $2V(V-1)$ has dimension "length to fourth power plus length squared", which does not have much sense. Could you post a screenshot of your textbook with this passage? Maybe there is an additional hypothesis somewhere?

Comment: Looking closer at it, I think it wasn't a mathematical proof but rather an observation of how the derivative could be written for the particular system. The textbook itself said "Consider again the system in Example 3.8. Given the chosen Lyapunov function candidate V = ..., the derivative V-dot can be written ... Looking back at Example 3.8, I think he's just rewriting it in a convenient notation that happens to exist for this particular system. So, I think this answers the question - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That relationship only applies for particular systems, such as the one the textbook was using. The particular system was:
$
\\
\dot x_1=x_1(x_1^2+x_2^2-2)-4x_1x_2^2  
\\
\dot x_2=4x_1^2x_2+x_2(x_1^2+x_2^2-2)
$

Comment: Why isn't this part of the question? (You should be able to edit your own question to add information like this.)